# Fullcalendar add custom button to each day

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How can I add custom buttons for each day in the fullCalendar?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that your best solution is probably the [dayRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender) callback which allows you to add extra HTML into the cell of each day before it is drawn on the calendar.

e.g. here's a super-simple example:

```
dayRender: function(info)
{
  info.el.innerHTML += "<button class='dayButton' data-date='" + info.date + "'>Click me</button>";
  info.el.style.padding = "20px 0 0 10px";
}
```

Live demo (including handled click event): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNjExGx

Comment: How do we do this in v5?

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge look at the day render hooks

Comment: it looks like the dayrender hooks are no longer available in v5

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge ?? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks