# FullCalander add custom div to each day

Tags: html, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using fullcalander 3.9.0. I want to add custom div to each date. I did not get any particular id for that date. One more specification is I want to display that custom div for the date which have event(s). If there is no any event than no custom div to display that date. I dont know how to do it.

I tried this url : [Fullcalendar add custom button to each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632845/fullcalendar-add-custom-button-to-each-day)

But it did not work for me.

I tried this jQuery but it is not working.

```
$( ".fc-event-container" ).each(function() {
          $( ".fc-day" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).append("<div class='addplusspan' >1</div> ");
          });
        });
```

This code display like this:-
[image]

I Want to display div in every date. Or I want to assign a div in each date.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDITED:-
I tried this code and it is near to result. I assumed that id:56,57 have events and data.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    var obj = [
    {
        "item1": {
            "Resource_Id": "56",
            "Days": "1",
            "Hours":"8"
        }
    },
    {
        "item2": {
            "Resource_Id": "56",
            "Days": "1",
            "Hours":"1"
        }
    },
    {
        "item3": {
            "Resource_Id": "57",
            "Days": "1",
            "Hours":"4"
        }
    },
    {
        "item4": {
            "Resource_Id": "57",
            "Days": "1",
            "Hours":"4"
        }
    }
    ];

    var main_item="";
    var key_name="";
    var key_full_name="";
    var resource_id;
    var days;
    var hours;
    var text="";
    
    for(var index = 0; index < obj.length; index++){
       //do something with obj[index]
       for(var index_value in obj[index]) {
            //console.log(ind);

            main_item += index_value +"<br> ";
            for(var key_name in obj[index][index_value]){
                //console.log(key_name, obj[index][index_value][key_name]);
                key_full_name = key_name;
                
                if(key_full_name == "Resource_Id"){
                    resource_id = obj[index][index_value][key_name];
                }
                else if(key_full_name == "Days"){
                    days = obj[index][index_value][key_name];
                    var day_count = 100 * days;
                }else if (key_full_name == "Hours") {
                    hours = obj[index][index_value][key_name];
                    var hour_count = 20 * hours;
                }
            } 
            jQuery( ".bsit_sche_width.fc-time-area.fc-widget-content.fc-unselectable").find('*[data-resource-id="'+resource_id+'"] td').append("<div class='addplusspan' style='display:block; position:absolute; left:"+day_count+"px; top:"+hour_count+"px;' >+</div> ");

       }
    } // first loop completed

});
```

I found this :-
[image]
This is some near to result.

Comment: Hi ,can you make this runnable ?

Comment: Swati, It is not runnable in fiddle. I tried it before i post here.

Comment: Then , its difficult to help . Try to create working demo code and let me know .